# Cleaning up text file of numbers to create CSV

Tags: python, csv, data-cleaning, txt

so I'm working on a project where I'm converting PDFs to a .txt file, which I'm converting to a CSV file using Python. So, I'm working with a this PDF: https://secure.in.gov/dcs/files/AssessmentDecisions201301.pdf and converting it to a text file using an OCR converter online.
This is a snip of what the data looks like

```
                               Sexual Abuse   Physical Abuse   Neglect



               Location/ 

    Region          Total         Sub     UnSub   Sub    UnSub   Sub    UnSub





  Statewide         Total         250     1143    185    1882    1409   7280
```

Then what I want to do is make it a readable CSV file that can be used for data analysis.
So, to read in my file this is the code I have:

```
filename = "AssessmentDecisions2013-01.txt"
file = open(filename, 'rt')
info = file.read()
file.close()
new = info.split()
```

The reason I'm splitting it is because the first column of the data has all of the numbers I need, but they're separated by tabs, so I'm trying to split them into their own columns. However, when trying to split the file, this is the output I get when using `print(new)`

```
['ÿþ', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00']
```

I'm relatively new at programming, so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this, but essentially, I'm just trying to split the different numbers of the report into their own columns.

I want the ideal csv to look like the following:

| region | county | s_assault_sub | s_assault_unsub |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Statewide | Total | 250 | 1143 |

| p_assault_sub | p_assault_unsub | neglect_sub | neglect_unsub |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 185 | 1882 | 1409 | 7280 |

If anyone has any tips or suggestions, I would really appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: Can you share expected data format?

Comment: @Alderven Hi yeah! So looking at the data example from the PDF, I want to split the numbers into the following corresponding columns: region, county, s_assault_sub, s_asssult_unsub, p_assault_sub, p_assault_unsub, neglect_sub, neglect_unsub. So, for example for the snip of the first row, the region would be Statewide, the county would be total, then 250, 1143, 185, 1182, 1409, and 7280 would go into the following columns.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.